# Salmon Multiple File SCRIPT giving error

Tags: rna-seq, sequence-alignment, bash, salmon, quantification

Hi I am using Salmon quantitation for multiple fastq paired files using following code

```
salmon_index="human_salmon_index"
fastq_dir="fastq/"
for dir in "${fastq_dir}"/SRR*
do
r1_file=$(find "$dir" -name "*_1.fastq")
r2_file=$(find "$dir" -name "*_2.fastq")
samp=$(basename "$dir")
echo "Processing sample ${samp}"
salmon quant -i "$salmon_index" -l A -1 "$r1_file" -2 "$r2_file" -p 10 -o "salmon_out/${samp}_quant"
done
```

and getting this error after it iterates over all files and start initial processing steps.

```
Processing sample SRR27756943_2.fastq
Version Info: This is the most recent version of salmon.
### salmon (selective-alignment-based) v1.10.0

Exception : [
The following errors were detected with the read files

======================================================

ERROR: file [] does not appear to exist!
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `find` operations return exactly one file each? The error seems to state that there were no files found for some run. Or it could also be that you have a file that matched your glob pattern that's not a dir, so the `find` operation fails.

Try this:

```
salmon_index="human_salmon_index"
fastq_dir=fastq
for dir in ${fastq_dir}/SRR*/
do
r1_file=$(find $dir -name "*_1.fastq")
r2_file=$(find $dir -name "*_2.fastq")
samp=$(basename $dir)
echo "Processing sample ${samp}"
echo salmon quant -i "$salmon_index" -l A -1 "$r1_file" -2 "$r2_file" -p 10 -o "salmon_out/${samp}_quant" | tee salmon_commands.cmd
done
```

Verify the contents of `salmon_commands.cmd` then use `bash` or `parallel` to run the actual commands.

Comment: Hi, I tried but getting this error
find: ‘fastq//SRR*/’: No such file or directory
find: ‘fastq//SRR*/’: No such file or directory
Processing sample SRR*
salmon quant -i ref_salmon/ -l A -1  -2  -p 10 -o salmon_out/SRR*_quant

Comment: Try without the quotes. I've made the required changes.